# Unable to see logging messages in django using the logging module

Tags: django, nginx, logging, gunicorn

I'm a newbie to logging. I added the code for logging in my `views.py` file and I added the settings as per the django documentation in my `settings.py` file. However, the logging.txt file shows other exceptions at `DEBUG` level or no output at `WARNING` level. The website is working properly and I have it live on an EC2 instance.

Here's the code for in my **views.py** file:

```
import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def index(request):
    ...
    logger.error("THIS IS A LOG ERROR!!!")
    logger.warning("THIS IS A LOG WARNING!!!")

    ...
    return render(...)
```

Here's the code in my **settings.py** file:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logging.txt',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger you have configured is named `django` which will match all code under the top level `django` package - essentially Django framework code.

For your own code, you'll need to configure a separate logger based on the name of your app, which will apply to loggers created with `logging.getLogger(__name__)` in any module inside that app. For example, if your app is called `myapp`:

```py
'myapp': {  # Will apply to myapp/views.py, myapp/models.py etc.
    'handlers': ['file'],
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'propagate': True,
}
```

In addition, it's a good idea to configure a root logger which acts as a "catch all" to log any messages that don't match an explicit logger. You can set the root logger to `ERROR` so that you don't miss any errors coming out of any part of the system. You use an empty string for the name of the root logger.

```py
'': {
    'handlers': ['file'],
    'level': 'ERROR',
}
```

So all together:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logging.txt',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {  # Logger for Django framework code
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'myapp': {  # Specific logger for your app
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        '': {  # Catch-all root logger
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I have added logger to my app but I'm not getting logs other than following.

```Not Found: /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
Not Found: /api/jsonws/invoke
Not Found: /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
Not Found: /index.php
Not Found: /mifs/.;/services/LogService
Not Found: /console/
Not Found: /wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/readme.txt
Not Found: /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml
Not Found: /_ignition/execute-solution
Not Found: /favicon.ico```